Error in R frailtypack function operation
I'm modeling repeated events on dataset of 84 panelists and 831 times survey participation and 49 exits (aka., terminal events) with joint frailty model using the frailtypanel() function from the frailtypack package. However, I encountered the following error:


Error in FUN(left, right) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types



However, my data contain all numeric variables except for id, which does not seem to violate the logic of the function. Or maybe it has something to do with the POSIXct class format ()?
It will be really appreciated if someone could point out the error in my data. Here're my data and replication code:


# load data
df <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2np1ad839teeejwuv4g9s/mrm.rds?rlkey=8vd754j2fkqku79zpts8uvbj2&st=ktfeg295&dl=1"))

str(df)
'data.frame':   3008 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ id             : int  25668 25668 25668 25668 25668 25668 25668 25668 25668 25668 ...
 $ sampled        : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ participate    : num  0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ reminder       : num  2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ gender         : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ age            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ time.start.days: num  0 0.278 14.762 31.445 31.448 ...
 $ time.end.days  : num  0.278 14.762 31.445 31.448 31.449 ...
 $ exit           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

# install.packages("frailtypack")
library(frailtypack)  # call required package

fit_joint_time <- frailtyPenal(
    Surv(time.start.days, time.end.days, participate) ~ gender + age + reminder + sampled + cluster(id) + terminal(exit),
    formula.terminalEvent = ~ gender + age,
    data = df,
    recurrentAG = T,
    n.knots = 2,
    kappa = c(10000,10000),
    cross.validation = F
)

# the error message
Error in FUN(left, right) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types



